# Netscaler Nitro API cannot get Service Groups

Tags: c#, sdk, netscaler

I am trying to use the .NET API to disable servers in my Netscaler.  I am able to get a list of VIPs and get a list of servers associated with those VIPs.  However, some VIPs have service groups associated with them.  This is where I am running into an issue.  When I reach a VIP that has a service group, I get a null exception error.  I am not sure where the service group information is stored in the VIP.  Here is my code:

```
nitro_service session = new nitro_service("<netscaler-IP>");
session.login("<username>", "<password>");

var lbServers = lbvserver.get(session);

foreach (var vip in lbServers)
{
    foreach (var service in lbvserver_servicegroup_binding.get(session, vip.name))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(vip.name);
        Console.Write(service.servicegroupname);
        Console.WriteLine(service.servicename);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I have tried checking to see if servicegroupname is null but it is always null, regardless if there is a service group or server associated with the VIP.

I have also tried to just get the service group without the VIP but lbvserver_servicegroup_binding only takes 2 arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.

I defined my servicegroup before my foreach.

```
var serviceGroups = lbvserver_servicegroup_binding.get(session, vip.name);
```

Then added an if serviceGroups !=null